# RainLoop emails autocomplete and additional data attributes

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to filter output for emials autocomplete suggestions as I need to add data attributes to them using `ajax.suggestions-post` hook but I'm not able to locate code responsible for rendering an output for

```
    $this->Plugins()->RunHook('ajax.suggestions-post', array(&$aResult, $sQuery, $oAccount, $iLimit));

    if ($iLimit < \count($aResult))
    {
        $aResult = \array_slice($aResult, 0, $iLimit);
    }

    return $this->DefaultResponse(__FUNCTION__, $aResult);
```

It is a part of `DoSuggestions()` function which uses autocomplete from jQuery UI but I'm missing part where is functionality to get `$aResult` bits and split them between `"Full Name"` bit and `<email>` bit for a suggestions which output looks like:

```
<div id="ui-id-X" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">"Full Name" <myemail@test.com></div>
```

Any tips how `$aResult` array can be passed to jQuery UI autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came up is not done via jQuery but RainLoop's JavaScript `oEmailItem.toLine` function (app.js file).